# How can I automate the rewording of dozens of Git commits?

Tags: git

For a long time when we were new to Git we did not delete merged branches, we just left them.  Now we have dozens of old branches that need to be deleted.  Before I delete them, however, I'd like to reword each of the commits on those branches to prepend the commit message with the branch name, eg "SCM-528: ...".

There are hundreds of commits that would need to be reworded, too many to do by hand with interactive rebases.  Is there any way I could automate the rewording of the commits?

Comment: You can give [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) a try.